# Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: localhost. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.herokuapp.com, DNS:herokuapp.com

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, session-cookies, next.js

I have an api created and hosted on `Heroku`. I have my web app running on localhost. I am using `NextJS` for my app. I am able to access all my apis hosted on Heroku via my web app which is running on `localhost`. I have one api which checks whether a cookie is available or not, I am calling the api in the `getInitialProps` method of the `_app.js` file of my `NextJS` app which is the entry point of the framework. If I comment that api call code then I don't get any error , but I need to check whether cookie is present or not so calling that code gives an error saying

```
Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: localhost. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.herokuapp.com, DNS:herokuapp.com
```

Also my `cookie` is not saved in the browser when I login. It works fine on `postman` so no problem from my api side and I can see the cookie in the postman.
I did set following in my NodeJS app

```
app.set("trust proxy", true);
```

I am using the `cookie-session` library in my `express` `Nodejs` app

Comment: Did you have any lead on this ? :)

Comment: did you solve it ? i am having same issues

Comment: Im running into this exact issue as well, did you manage to find any solutions?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I could really use some help with this issue.

Comment: Can you try setting this as environment variable `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

Comment: Does this help? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/session-affinity May require some code changes too.

Comment: Please post the contents of your /etc/hosts just to be sure. The file is in Windows/system32/drivers/etc.

Answer (score 0):

in my case https://github.com/ushelp/EasyQRCodeJS-NodeJS/issues/30#issuecomment-1221164642 i always manual on create systemd file but i got same issue when tried using pm2.

i have an issue from my **ecosystem.config.js** where thats handle of env ( **process.env.any** )

something your value to pointing / save / load online its still on localhost or an ipaddress instead of your custom domain on VPS server these issue when u are using certbot instead of buying ssl.

these random error, in my case you can check on the above link for more detail ***but in short its just because you are using ipaddress or localhost in your code***.

```
try to change your hardcode everything that point to correct env

but in your case you are using heroku thats mean you need to define
on reveal vars because heroku is not using an env file
```

here more for you
( put all your env to ) `heroku --> setting --> Config Vars --> Reveal Config Vars`

Answer (score -1):

Read this article:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl

It's about installing certificates.
For me it looks that just the certificate is signed for `localhost`. The browser will reject it, because you access the site by another domain name.

So you have to self-sign a certificate and upload it, or buy a trusted certificate.